# add link location after each link with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some links in my web page like this :

```
<a href="http://test1.com">Test 1</a>
<a href="http://test2.com">Test 2</a>
<a href="http://test3.com">Test 3</a>
<a href="http://test4.com">Test 4</a>
```

and I want to add `href` attribute after each link with **jquery**. actually I want to have something like this in my web page :

```
Test 1 (http://test1.com)
Test 2 (http://test2.com)
Test 3 (http://test3.com)
Test 4 (http://test4.com)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You can modify the html of links using jQuery as shown below -

```js
$(function(){
  $('a').each(function(){
     //take link text
     var text = $(this).html();
     var href = ' (' + $(this).attr('href') + ')';
     //edit link text with href
     $(this).html(text + href );
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://test1.com">Test 1</a>
<a href="http://test2.com">Test 2</a>
<a href="http://test3.com">Test 3</a>
<a href="http://test4.com">Test 4</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the current HTML with its href and then set it as html again.

```js
$(function() {

  $("a").each(function() {
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML + " (" + this.href + ")";
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://test1.com">Test 1</a><br>
<a href="http://test2.com">Test 2</a><br>
<a href="http://test3.com">Test 3</a><br>
<a href="http://test4.com">Test 4</a><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

See, the `$('tagName')` selector returns a collection of jQuery objects so you can directly use the `.text(fn)` method on each anchor with a callback function which has two parameters `(index, text)` first one is the index of the current  element and second one is the `text` value of it.

You can use `.text(fn)` to append the `href` with text of each anchor:

```js
$('a').text(function(i, txt){
   return txt + ' (' +$(this).attr('href')+')'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://test1.com">Test 1</a><br>
<a href="http://test2.com">Test 2</a><br>
<a href="http://test3.com">Test 3</a><br>
<a href="http://test4.com">Test 4</a><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery **.atrr()** is the answer for you

here is an example from w3schools how it works:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_attr_set
code is also below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#w3s").attr("href", "http://www.w3schools.com/jquery");
    });
});
```